# Zend Framework along with Backbone.js

Tags: php, zend-framework, backbone.js, coffeescript

Hi if i would like to create a backbone app/assets folder in my zend application where would most probably will i place it? Backbone app folder consist of `Javascript,Stylesheets and Templates`

Simply put this is how backbone works with rails

```
routes.rb

  resources :entries
```

Rails controller for entries/index

```
class EntriesController < ApplicationController
    respond_to :json

    def index
        respond_with Entry.all
    end
end
```

Backbone collection simply understood if the url is at /entries with these code

```
class Blog.Collections.Entries extends Backbone.Collection
    url: '/entries'
```

in Backbone router

```
class Blog.Routers.Entries extends Backbone.Router
  routes:
    '': 'index'
    'entries/:id': 'show'

  initialize: ->
    @collection = new Blog.Collections.Entries()
    @collection.fetch()

  index: ->
    view = new Blog.Views.EntriesIndex(collection: @collection)
    #alert 'hi'
    $('#container').html(view.render().el)
  show: (id) ->
    alert "Entry #{id}"
```

it then render to `Backbone.View`

```
class Blog.Views.EntriesIndex extends Backbone.View

    template: JST['entries/index']

    initialize: ->
        @collection.on('reset',@render,this)
    render: ->

        $(@el).html(@template(entries: @collection))
        this
```

template to render assets/templates/entries/index.jst.eco

```
<h1>Blog</h1>

<ul>
<% for entry in @entries.models: %>
    <li><%= entry.get('name')%></li>
<% end %>
</ul>
```

finally init the app with assets/javascripts/blog.js.coffee

```
window.Blog =
  Models: {}
  Collections: {}
  Routers: {}
  Views: {}
  initialize: -> 
    new Blog.Routers.Entries()
    Backbone.history.start()

$(document).ready ->
    Blog.initialize()
```

The above MVC pattern of Backbone.js is interesting, but i would like to implement with Zend Framework, so what config i must change in order to use like we use it in rails.Also how we handle the template for rendering the view? Thanks

Comment: The question is not clear. Backbone is a client side library, designed to work with RESTFul services. It is agnostic to the implementation of the REST server on the backend.
What exactly are you asking?

Comment: How to use it with Zend Application? I know javascript is client side, but they all have their own way of implement within the scripting language. Mostly Backbone.js is use with Rails. But i would like to know how we include it with Zend Framework.

Comment: .. and why you explain how you do that in Rails ....

Comment: cause all example use Rails for Backbone..i want try out with Zend Framework

Answer (score 0):

You would put your Backbone app in your public folder (where all your CSS and Javascript files are).

For the template you can use your preferred templating engine, I use Underscore to save having to include another library. An example of this would be:

```
window.product_v = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: _.template("<article><img src='<%=icon%>'/> <% } %><article>"),

    render: function () {
        var self = this;
        this.model.fetch({
            processData: true,
            success: function (m) {
                var prod = $("<div/>", {
                        'html': self.template(m.toJSON())
                }).appendTo('.content');

            }
        });
    }
});

window.product_m = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: '/api/get_product'
});
```

In your model you would define your data source in "urlRoot", which is where you would reference, presumably, the path to one of your Zend controllers.